# Loading CSV file in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
diabetes_dataset = pd.read_csv('//Users/rac07317/Documents/Projects')
```

I am currently coding along a machine learning project to understand the work flow. However my CSV file is not showing in it's path as in .csv. I have searched all over but I have not seen a similar issue.

IsADirectoryError: error code I am receiving

Any guidance would be much appreciated ☺️

Comment: Might be the double slash, (should only be one), before `Users` in your path.

Comment: I added the file in projects. It's diabetes.csv when I downloaded it then I moved it over to the project folder

Comment: You should be able to reason through this.  The error is "IsADirectoryError", and you just told us it is a directory.  How did you think it would know which file to load?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error but then I receive NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 diabetes_dataset = pd.read_csv('/Users/rac07317/Documents/Projects/diabetes.csv')


NameError: name 'pd' is not defined. Also will I always have to add the .csv at the end myself. Why did it not appear when I clicked get info on the file?

Comment: maybe you forgot to run `import pandas as pd`

Comment: That's because you can have several files with the same name but with different extensions: 
https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! I really appreciate it

Comment: Shouldn't there be a c or d directory in the beginning of the path? If that doesn't work, move the csv file to desktop and try to read it from there.

Comment: @MoaazSiddiqui just fyi that's one of the differences between windows and Unix paths.

Comment: @rayad Oh ok, never really used Unix, my bad.